# How do I to convert an XML formatted String into a single line XML string with no spaces in grails/groovy?

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

I am wondering if there is an easier way to converted an XML formatted string with line breaks and tabs into one single line xml string with no formatting.
currently I am thinking of doing

```
s.replaceAll("\n",""); 
s.replaceAll("\t","");
```

but is there a more better way to do this in grails/groovy?

input XML:

```
<chart subCaption="Mon, 24 Oct 2011-Tue, 21 Feb 2012" outCnvBaseFont="Arial" outCnvBaseFontSize="12" xAxisName="Day of the Month" yAxisName="Distinct User Count" formatNumberScale="0" decimalPrecision="0" showvalues="0" animation="1" numdivlines="3" numVdivlines="0" lineThickness="3" rotateNames="1">
  <categories>
    <category Label="Nov/28" showName="1" />
    <category Label="Nov/29" showName="0" />
    <category Label="Nov/30" showName="0" />
    <category Label="Dec/01" showName="0" />
    <category Label="Dec/02" showName="1" />
    <category Label="Dec/03" showName="0" />
    <category Label="Dec/04" showName="0" />
  </categories>
  <dataset seriesName="view/export" color="F5497D" showValue="1" alpha="100" anchorAlpha="0" lineThickness="2">
    <set value="0" />
    <set value="0" />
    <set value="0" />
    <set value="0" />
    <set value="0" />
    <set value="0" />
    <set value="0" />
  </dataset>
</chart>
```

output xml

```
<chart subCaption="Mon, 24 Oct 2011-Tue, 21 Feb 2012" outCnvBaseFont="Arial" outCnvBaseFontSize="12" xAxisName="Day of the Month" yAxisName="Distinct User Count" formatNumberScale="0" decimalPrecision="0" showvalues="0" animation="1" numdivlines="3" numVdivlines="0" lineThickness="3" rotateNames="1"><categories><category Label="Nov/28" showName="1" /><category Label="Nov/29" showName="0" /><category Label="Nov/30" showName="0" /><category Label="Dec/01" showName="0" /><category Label="Dec/02" showName="1" /><category Label="Dec/03" showName="0" /><category Label="Dec/04" showName="0" /></categories><dataset seriesName="view/export" color="F5497D" showValue="1" alpha="100" anchorAlpha="0" lineThickness="2"><set value="0" /><set value="0" /><set value="0" /><set value="0" /><set value="0" /><set value="0" /><set value="0" /></dataset></chart>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script might be also helpful:

```
unpretty = pretty.replaceAll(/>(\n|\t|\s)*</, '><')
                 .replaceAll(/\n|\t/, ' ')
                 .replaceAll(/\s+/, ' ')
```

Removes extra \n, \t, \s between angle brackets and converts extra \n, \t, \s into single whitespace inside/outside tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get rid of \t and \n, then you can do something like this:

```
s.collect { it != "\n" && it != "\t" ? it : "" }.join()
```

This, of course assumes there are no semantically relevant whitespace chars as attribute values.

This will achieve the same affect as your example, but it will not do anything to remove spaces.  Removing spaces is a lot more difficult since you need at least one whitespace char between attribute names and tag names and you can't remove them from inside the values.

I don't think there is a short or elegant way to do this.  You would need to work with a real XML parser.  Something like an XMLSlurper would be a good start.

---

EDIT

Another possibility is something like this:

```
def root = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
new XmlNodePrinter(preserveWhitespace:false).print(root.body[0])
```

The problem with this solution is that the string is pretty-printed with newlines and indentation, but you can combine the first example with the second to transform the pretty-printed string.

Comment: I tried this and it looks ok... but there is lot of spacing left between the tags. The larger size of the xml string is causing it not be able to be passed to next page for chart rendering..

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I can think of is to use a regex to replace all whitespace characters between the angle brackets, like so:

```
def test = '''<chart subCaption="Mon, 24 Oct 2011-Tue, 21 Feb 2012" outCnvBaseFont="Arial" outCnvBaseFontSize="12" xAxisName="Day of the Month" yAxisName="Distinct User Count" formatNumberScale="0" decimalPrecision="0" showvalues="0" animation="1" numdivlines="3" numVdivlines="0" lineThickness="3" rotateNames="1">
  <categories>
    <category Label="Nov/28" showName="1" />
    <category Label="Nov/29" showName="0" />
    <category Label="Nov/30" showName="0" />
    <category Label="Dec/01" showName="0" />
    <category Label="Dec/02" showName="1" />
    <category Label="Dec/03" showName="0" />
    <category Label="Dec/04" showName="0" />
  </categories>
  <dataset seriesName="view/export" color="F5497D" showValue="1" alpha="100" anchorAlpha="0" lineThickness="2">
    <set value="0" />
    <set value="0" />
    <set value="0" />
    <set value="0" />
    <set value="0" />
    <set value="0" />
    <set value="0" />
  </dataset>
</chart>
'''

println test.replaceAll(/>\s+</, '><')
```

This worked in my test.  Also, since angle brackets aren't valid inside attributes, this shouldn't affect any of the internal content.

It does not, however, remove extra whitespace between attributes.